# Как уменьшить расстояние между item RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно уменьшить расстояние между элементами списка RecyclerView?
Прокрутка сделана горизонтальная, через LinearLayoutManager
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_recycler_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте `android:layout_width` у верхнего `LinearLayout` с `match_parent` на `wrap_content`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- вот здесь -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
```

Объясняю: каждый элемент создаётся отдельно по вашей разметке, и у вас получилось так, что родительский лейаут занимает по ширине всего уже своего родителя, которым выступает уже активити, и в итоге вы видите только один элемент на экране.

Comment: Добавил разметку

Comment: @Вячеслав дополнил ответ